Automatically pass Cypress test after 1 minute of duration
How to program test which passes when 1 minute of duration is being achieved? No matter current stage of test being run.
From comments:
The test should pass if the endpoint returns 200, or if there is no response from there for a minute.

Please give us more details on the matter. What are you trying to achieve? Little bit of context please.

The test should pass if the endpoint returns 200, or if there is no response from there for a minute.

...that's a strange definition of "passing". In any case, I think this question is clear enough.

Since from the comment we now know that you are talking about a request, the question becomes answerable.
Your test should be a variation of the Request Polling example given in the documentation.
Something like this:
function req (start) {
  
  if (Date.now() > start + 60_000 ) {   
    return                               // without failing
  }

  cy.request({
    url: ...
    failOnStatusCode: false              // allows testing of status
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    if (resp.status === 200 && resp.body.ok === true) {
      return
    }

    req(start)
  })
}

req(Date.now())

